# Mocking a class in PowerMock

Tags: junit, powermock

I am using PowerMocking for JUNIT and Iam new to PowerMock.

I want to mock one class which is non static.

The class scenario goes as follows.

```
 public class Export extends MyUtil implements ExportFormatting<DeptSummaryByDCDTO, LmReportsInputDTO>{

    public String createPDF(List<DeptSummaryByDCDTO> summaryDtoList, LmReportsInputDTO inputDto){

     }

    public String createPDF(Map<String, DeptSummaryByDCDTO> paramMap,
        LmReportsInputDTO paramK) {


    }
```

}

The calling class is as follows.

```
 public static Response getMultiplePackSku{
       filePath = new Export(inputDto).createPDF(resultList,null);
 }
```

The Question is,

I am trying to test the above class using powermock.

Can anybody tell how to mock the line **filePath.....**

Comment: downvoter, next time please provide a comment as to why

Answer (score 2):

You need to first mock the constructor and return an `Export` mock. On the returned mock you need to record the call to `createPDF`. The tricky part is the constructor mocking. I'll give you an example, hopefully you'll get all of it:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // This annotation is for using PowerMock
@PrepareForTest(Export.class) // This annotation is for mocking the Export constructor
public class MyTests {

    private mockExport;

    @Before
    public void setUp () {
        // Create the mock
        mockExport = PowerMock.createMock(Export.class)
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithConstructor() {
        SomeDtoClass inputDto = PowerMock.createMock(SomeDtoClass.class); 
        PowerMock.expectNew(Export.class, inputDto).andReturn(mockExport);
        PowerMock.replay(mockExport, Export.class);
        expect(mockExport.createPDF(resultList, null);


        // Run the tested method.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of how to mock a constructor call: [MockConstructor](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)