# Inject Mocks for objects created by Factory classes

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {        
    private Apple apple;

    public void myMethod() {
       apple = AppleFactory.createInstance(someStringVariable);
       ....
       ....
       ....
    }
}
```

And the Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

        @InjectMocks 
        MyClass myClass;

        @Test
        public void myMethod(){
         ...
         ...
         ...
        }
    }
```

How could I inject an Apple instance as a mock in MyClass?

Comment: Regarding the first answer of Avi & Ev0oD. Abstract classes can only be extended and not implemented, ie `public abstract class AppleFactory { public abstract Apple createInstance(final String str); } public class AppleFactoryImpl extends AppleFactory { public Apple createInstance(final String str) { // Implementation } }`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have 3 possibilities to solve this:

**Abstract factory**: Instead of using a static method, use a concrete factory class:

```
public abstract class AppleFactory {
    public Apple createInstance(final String str);
}

public class AppleFactoryImpl implements AppleFactory {
    public Apple createInstance(final String str) { // Implementation }
}
```

In your test class, mock the factory:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private AppleFactory appleFactoryMock;

    @Mock
    private Apple appleMock;

    @InjectMocks 
    MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(appleFactoryMock.createInstance(Matchers.anyString()).thenReturn(appleMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void myMethod(){
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
}
```

**PowerMock**: Use PowerMock to create a mock of a static method. Look at [my answer to a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882873/1920149) to see how it's done.

**Testable class**: Make the `Apple` creation wrapped in a `protected` method and create a test class that overrides it:

```
public class MyClass {
   private Apple apple;

   public void myMethod() {
       apple = createApple();
       ....
       ....
       ....
   }

   protected Apple createApple() {
       return AppleFactory.createInstance(someStringVariable);
   }
}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private Apple appleMock;

    @InjectMocks 
    MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void myMethod(){
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }

    private class TestableMyClass extends MyClass {
       @Override
       public void createApple() {
          return appleMock;
       }
    }
}
```

Of course, in your test class you should test `TestableMyClass` and not `MyClass`.

I'll tell you my opinion on each of the methods:

1. The abstract factory method **is the best one** - This is a clear design that hides the implementation details
2. The testable class - Is the second option which requires minimum changes
3. The `PowerMock` option is my least favorite - Instead of going for a better design, you ignore and hide your problem. But that's still a valid option.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I have to use Mockito in my situation so I'll go with Abstract Factory or TestableClass options.

Comment: @saravana_pc - I added my ranking to the issues. Nevertheless, you can use `mockito` with power mock. Instead of using the `@Mock` and `@InjectMock` you can use their equivalent methods (and thus you can get rid of the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` declaration)

Comment: when implementing the abstract factory pattern, wont an interface be more appropriate?

Comment: I do not understand the necessity of an abstract class, wouldn't it work with the implementation only ?
Also, while I like this idea, it somehow devoid the factory from it's purpose (you need to create an instance of the factory). Now mockito can mock static methods, but I cannot use the newer version :/

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the solution proposed by Avi, you can choose a fourth possibility:

Inject into Factory:
This is, for me, the best option when you already have code to refacrot. With this solution you don't have to change porduction code but only factory class and test.

```
public class AppleFactory
{
    private static Apple _injectedApple;

    public static createInstance(String str)
    {
        if (_injectedApple != null)
        {
            var currentApple = _injectedApple;
            _injectedApple = null;
            return currentApple;
        }

        //standard implementation
    }

    public static setInjectedApple(Apple apple)
    {
        _injectedApple = apple;
    }
}
```

Now you can use your static factory simply:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private Apple appleMock;

    @InjectMocks 
    MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        AppleFactory.setInjectedApple(appleMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void myMethod(){
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you test AppleFactory then?