# PowerMock whenNew without @PrepareForTest?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

This is my situation, I have 2 very simple classes:

```
public class B {

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("doSomething B reached");
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class A {

public void doSomething(){
    B b = new B();
    b.doSomething();
    System.out.println("doSomething A reached");
}
```

}

I want to test method doSomething of class A with Mockito. Therefor, I want to mock an instance of class B and give this to A when it is instantiating class B. I don't want b.doSomething() to be reached at all, for isolation reasons.

I know I can reach this behaviour by creating the following unittest:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestA {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(A.class)
    public void testDoSomethingOfA() throws Exception{
        A a = PowerMockito.spy(new A());
        B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(b);
        a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

which results in output:

```
doSomething A reached
```

So this work! However, my problem now is that we use the Jococo plugin for test coverage. Jococo doesn't cover code tested with the @PrepareForTest(A.class) statement. And my company values accurate code testing coverage.

My question: Is there another way around to give A an instantiation of B without having to use the @PrepareForTest statement?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't making `B` a constructor argument of `A` an option? Or at least a factory giving `B` instances? Or using dependency injection?

Comment: This would be my last resort! But I would really like to not touch the existing code before refactoring it. And before refactoring I would really like solid unit tests.

Comment: I know the code isn't pretty and I agree that either a factory or dependency injection would be a better solution, but at this point I can't touch the code

Comment: Using `PowerMock` is avoiding the problem instead of fixing it (something like @fge suggested). I support refactor it to get a constructor argument or create `B` with a factory. Also look at the option I gave here for mocking something like this without `PowerMock`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879804/inject-mocks-for-objects-created-by-factory-classes/21879866#21879866

Look at the Testable class solution

Comment: Thanks Avi, I think that for now I'll have to change a bit of code indeed. I'll probably make a protected method that gives a new instance of B back, and I'll override it in my unit tests (no matter how ugly this is in the real code, but this can't get any worse at this point anyway). If you give an answer, I will vote for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes, use an agent: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent

Answer (score 0):

@Rens Groenveld: After integrating PowerMockAgent, did you make any changes in your test class or source code ? I tried integrating PowerMockAgent and removed my main source class from @PrepareForTest but the behavior is same (creating new instance instead of mock).

I have tried jacoco offline instruments and many other solution, It did not work.

I can not post to your comment (needs 50 points) hence added as answer.