# How to test a static method without running a piece of code in it

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

A piece of code is like this:

```
public class ClassToTest {
    public static A method1(arguments here){
        //a log of code here
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }
}
```

The problem is the constructor call `new A()` is in a library and I don't want method1 to call this constructor in my test because it is not necessary for my current test and it contains some network connections. I want my unit test get rid of any external dependencies.

Generally in a unit test, we don't want to do any modification to the source code. But in order to test the critical logic in method1, It is acceptable to make some reasonable change to the source code.

At first I think I could move the `new A()` to another method and build a subclass and then override that method. This change is also reasonable without considering testing so I think it is acceptable. But adding a flag for test only is not acceptable.

But I cannot do this because the method I need to test is static.

Is there any other way to test this piece of code without running the line `A a = new A()`?

Comment: I answered a question that asked something very similar. I suggested 3 solutions, all of them would work out for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879804/inject-mocks-for-objects-created-by-factory-classes/21879866#21879866

For the first solution (mocking the factory) you can do the same here by wrapping the static call in a concrete class implementation

Comment: Why not just extract out a method or class that contains the logic that you do want to test, and test that?

Comment: Then it means the test pass once, it will pass forever. @NamshubWriter

Comment: @StarPinkER what kinds of changes would you like to cause the test to fail?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want that method to introduce state, then use [`PowerMockito.mockStatic()`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.4/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#mockStatic%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to mock the return value.  This makes the assumption that your static method has no side effects, and if it doesn't, you *really* should write it so that it doesn't.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ClassToTestTest {
    private ClassToTest classMock;
    private ClassToTest testObject;
    @Before
    public void init() {
        testObject = new ClassToTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void example() {
        Object args = new Object();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassToTest.class);
        doReturn(new A()).when(ClassToTest.class, "method1", args);
   }
}
```

`doReturn` will allow you to set up what it's going to ultimately give back after execution of your static method.

Comment: This is how you mock the static method right? But the logic I want to test is in method1. What I do want to mock is the new A() not method1.